# how to send json object from server to jsp and receive a response on jsp

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp

My java server receives JSON from JSP and make some operation and I try to send JSON object to JSON in the following way:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{

    JSONObject newObj = new JSONObject();

    try {
        newObj = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("jsonData"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int  val2 = 0;
    int val1 = 0;

    try {
        val2 = Integer.parseInt(newObj.getJSONObject("mydata").getString("number2"));
        val1 = Integer.parseInt(newObj.getJSONObject("mydata").getString("number1"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(val2 + val1);
    Double d =  Math.pow(val1, 2);

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();

    try {
        obj.put("results",d);
        obj.put("resultText","foo");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    writer.println(obj);
    writer.flush();
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

My JSP where I send JSON to server and try to receive JSON object response from server

```
<body>
   <h3>Please enter a number to Square : </h3>
   <input style="width: 33px; margin-left: 2px; " type="text" id="number1" name="number1">
   <input style="width: 33px; margin-left: 2px;" type="text" id="number2" name="number2">
   <input type="button" onclick="callServlet();" value="Calc">
   <input style="font-family: cursive; border:none" type="text"   id="result" />
   <input style="font-family: cursive; border:none; width: 100%" type="text"  value=""  id="resultText" />

 </body>
 <script>
        function callServlet() {
            var input1 = document.getElementById('number1').value;
            var input2 = document.getElementById('number2').value;
            var myData = {"mydata": {"number1": input1, "number2": input2}};
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/AjaxServletCalculator",
                data: {jsonData: JSON.stringify(myData)},
                dataType: "json",

                //if received a response from the server
                success: function (data) {
                    //our country code was correct so we have some information to display

                        var json = JSON.parse(data);        
                        alert(json["resultText"]);        
                       /*document.getElementById('number1').value = data.*/        
                }
            });
        }
 </script>
```

pleas help find the problem on which the program does not work

Comment: Do you get an error message? Have you checked in the browser network console what the server returns to the ajax request?

Comment: I don't have any error message
but that's what I could find, maybe it will help you
<img src="http://goo.gl/6QkHha" width="100" height="100">

Comment: Yes, that helps. It seems that you haven't included jQuery correctly. The $ reference is unknown for your browser.

Comment: how i can use ajax method without $ character
As far as I know ajax method begins with character $

Comment: `$.ajax` is the short form for `jQuery.ajax` you need to add jQuery to your html. Add the following code inside of your `<head>`- or `<body>`-tag and it should work: `<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I added
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
but it did not help
I have an error which points to a line JSON.parse
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o (index):16$.ajax.success (index):16success jquery-1.2.6.min.js:29jQuery.extend.ajax.onreadystatechange jquery-1.2.6.min.js:28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right `JSON.parse(data)` resulted in an error.

Also wrap your script in a `document.ready` function `$(function(){ ... });` to be sure that the DOM is ready before you access it.

The rest of your code is working. I just commented the parameters to the server because I have no backend that can handle it.

The jsFiddle to the demo below is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/j3qk1pLw/).

```js
$(function () {
    function callServlet() {
        var input1 = $("#number1").val(); //document.getElementById('number1').value;
        var input2 = $("#number2").val(); //document.getElementById('number2').value;
        var myData = {
            "mydata": {
                "number1": input1,
                "number2": input2
            }
        };
        //console.log(myData);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/547f86501713955b0a8ed4da',  //"/AjaxServletCalculator",
            data: {
                //jsonData: JSON.stringify(myData) // this works but mocky.io doesn't support it
            },
            dataType: "json",

            //if received a response from the server
            success: function (json) {
                //our country code was correct so we have some information to display
                console.log(json);
                //var json = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(json.data);
                /*document.getElementById('number1').value = data.*/
            }
        });
    }
    
    $('#calcBtn').click(function() {
        callServlet();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Please enter a number to Square : </h3>

<input style="width: 33px; margin-left: 2px; " type="text" id="number1" name="number1">
<input style="width: 33px; margin-left: 2px;" type="text" id="number2" name="number2">
<input type="button" id="calcBtn" value="Calc">
<input style="font-family: cursive; border:none" type="text" id="result" />
<input style="font-family: cursive; border:none; width: 100%" type="text" value="" id="resultText" />
```

Comment: `alert(json.data);` should be `alert(json.resultText);` as in servlet` obj.put("results",d);
        obj.put("resultText","foo"); ` there is nothing like `data`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that. `json.data` is just for my mock. `json.resultText` is right, if your server returns it.

Comment: I did everything as described but got some errors, that's a screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/woczbtengkpdgmv/001.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Remove line 49 from your code and change line 50 to `alert(json.resultText);`. If that results in an error you could also do `console.log(json);` to see what keys are available in your server response.

Comment: I thank you and I understood everything works, the problem was this string var json = JSON.parse(data);

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script>
 function callServlet() {
var input1 = document.getElementById('number1').value;
var input2 = document.getElementById('number2').value;
var myData = {"mydata": {"number1": input1, "number2": input2}};
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/AjaxServletCalculator",
    data: {jsonData: JSON.stringify(myData)},
    dataType: "json",

    //if received a response from the server
    success: function (data) {
        //our country code was correct so we have some information to display

          //  var json = JSON.parse(data);        
            alert(data.resultText);        
           /*document.getElementById('number1').value = data.*/        
      }
  });
 }
</script>
```

try above

remove
`var json = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Really the problem was that now everything is working very grateful for the help!